# Javascript: Finding shared values across multiple array

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

What this should be able to do is take in a 2D array filled with one letter values and return an array of all the shared values. This is what I have so far:

```
var res = array[0].filter(function(x){
        return array.every(function(y){
             return y.indexOf(x) >= 0
        })
    });
return res;
```

This is in some form of working state but only under certain condition which makes it very hit and miss. 
Working as intended:

```
var array = [["x","x"],
             ["x","x","x"]];
```

This returns the expected array of ["x","x"] but when like this:

```
var array = [["x","x","x"],
             ["x","x"]];
```

It returns ["x","x","x"]

As you can see the two arrays only share 2 common x's but the code doesn't reflect that in different situations. Also it should be able to handle arrays with other letters like so:

```
var array = [["x","x","z","y","y"],
             ["x,"x","x","y"],
             ["x","x","z","y"]];
```

With something like this it should return ["x","x","y"] as all arrays share 2 common x's and 1 common y

Comment: So you want a function that you can pass in an arbitrary number of arrays to, and then get back common values, regardless of index ?

Comment: There is no `y` in the 3rd array.

Comment: Yes, I didn't make that clear with how I set up the examples but yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combination of `.every` and `.filter`, use `.indexOf` to check whether a element exists in an array or not.

```js
var array = [
  ["x", "x", "z", "y", "y"],
  ["x", "x", "x", "y"],
  ["x", "x", "z", "y"]
];

var res = array[0].filter(function(x) {
  return array.every(function(y) {
    if (y.indexOf(x) != -1) {
      y[y.indexOf(x)] = Infinity;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  })
})

alert(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, using Array methods only availble from IE9 etc.

```js
function compareValues() {
    var arrs = [].slice.call(arguments).sort(function(a,b) {
     return a.length > b.length; // always iterate shortest array
    });
    
    return arrs.shift().filter(function(x, i) { // filter the first array
     return arrs.every(function(arr) {       // if all other arrays
            return arr[i] === x;                // have the same value at the same index
        })
    });
}

var result = compareValues(["x","x","x","y"], 
                           ["x","x","z","y"], 
                           ["x","x","z","y","y"]);

alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a proposal with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for nondestructive search.

```js
var array = [
        ["x", "x", "z", "y", "y"],
        ["x", "x", "x", "y"],
        ["x", "x", "z", "y"]
    ],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        var last = {};
        return r.filter(function (b) {
            var p = a.indexOf(b, last[b] || 0);
            if (~p) {
                last[b] = p + 1;
                return true;
            }
        });
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```